# Instantiating javascript module from Angular2 causing errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have an angular service, from which I would like to consume a plain javascript module.

When I instantiate it from he constructor I get the following error:

`TypeError: Engine is not a constructor`

My service is as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from "angular2/core";
import * as Engine from './engine';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor() {
      this.engine = new Engine(); // causing error
  }

  doStuff() {
    return this.engine.doStuff();
  }

}
```

And my module code:

```
var _ = require('lodash'); 

function Engine() { 
    this.stuff = [];
};

WorkoutEngine.prototype.doStuff = function() { 
    console.log('do stuff');
};

module.exports = Engine;
```

I can't figure out where I am going wrong?

Comment: what is your `moduleResolution` property set to in `tsconfig.json` file ??

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to inject Engine to the constructor of MyService,

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  // Let angular inject the engine.   
  constructor(private engine: Engine) {

  }

 .....    
}
```

Comment: I am not using typescript, doesn't it need to be in the @inject format for that to work?

Comment: I am not sure then. Isn't your service not a typescript code ?